# Why does bash try to execute strings in a string substitution?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, string

My script is supposed to take input from a pipe and replace newline characters with commas, using the bash's string substitution:

```
#! /bin/bash

read -d -r input 
echo $input 
$input=${input//\n/,}
echo $input
```

However, instead of replacing the newline character, bash tries to execute the first matching pattern:

```
echo -e "this\nis\na\ntest\n" | test.sh
```

will give the following output:

```
test.sh: line 5: this: command not found
```

and the variable `$input` is not changed. Double or single quotes did not help either. I'm using bash version 4.3.11 on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$` from the assignment line inside the loop. You're trying to use the value as the name of the variable you're assigning to, which is causing Very Strange Behavior.

Comment: Using a second variable name resolves the problem. It's weird that you can't do this in bash. But why do I get the same problem with just the line `${input//\n/,}` without any assignment?

Comment: Because at that point, you're trying to execute the variable's value, not echo it. You have to have an `echo` command in front of the variable if you're not assigning it (the modified value) to another variable.